# Solving for $x$ for $\frac{20,000}{21,000 + x} - 1 = \frac{-x}{20,000 + \frac{1}{2} (-x)} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I was solving some equations and I stumbled upon this problem.

Solving for $x$ for $$\frac{20,000}{21,000 + x} - 1 = \frac{-x}{20,000 + \frac{1}{2} (-x)} $$
 I was wondering what's the fastest way to solve for $x$.  Or you just have to brute force it?

Comment: Fastest way? Just dump it into a computer algebra system ;) You can do it by hand by cross multiplying and solving the resulting quadratic equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{20,000}{21,000 + x} - 1 = \frac{-x}{20,000 + \frac{1}{2} (-x)} $$

$$\frac{-1,000-x}{21,000 + x}  = \frac{-x}{20,000 + \frac{1}{2} (-x)} $$

If you cross multiply them, we get a quadratic equation and we use the quadratic formula.